# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException WELD-001334 Unsatisfied dependencies for type MyInterface with qualifiers @Any @MyAnnotation

Tags: java, jboss, annotations, cdi, javabeans

I have a Java 8 project and a JBoss 7.1.0GA server.
I have a batch class with a global variable

```
@EJB
public MyInterface delegate;
```

which is defined as an instance of DelegateClass in my ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <module-name>moduleName</module-name>
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>ejbName</ejb-name>
        <business-remote>MyInterface</business-remote>
        <ejb-class>DelegateClass</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

I have some implementations of MyInterface, so in my class DelegateClass I want to wrap an implementation of MyInterface and set it by an enum constant. 
Here the code:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class DelegateClass implements MyInterface {

@Inject
@Any
protected Instance<MyInterface> instance;

protected MyInterface selectedImpl;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selectedImpl = instance.select(MyLiteralAnnotation.create(MyEnum.value)).get();
}
```

Here is the code of my literal annotation class:

```
public class MyLiteralAnnotation extends AnnotationLiteral<MyAnnotation> implements MyAnnotation {

private final MyEnum value;

private MyLiteralAnnotation(MyEnum value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public MyEnum getValue() {
    return value;
}

public static MyLiteralAnnotation create(MyEnum value) {
    return new MyLiteralAnnotation(value);
}
```

}

the annotation I created:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR }) 
@Qualifier 
public @interface MyAnnotation {

MyEnum getValue();
}
```

and the implementation I want to have from the instance.select(...)

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@MyAnnotation(MyEnum.value)
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
....
}
```

I debug the application on my server, but when I try to instantiate the selectImpl field with instance.select(...), I have the exception:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException WELD-001334 Unsatisfied dependencies for type MyInterface with qualifiers @Any @MyAnnotation

Can someone help me, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem adding the annotation @ApplicationScope over the delegate class definition.

Answer (score 1):

The exception seems to occur because CDI does not find a bean annotated with @Any and @MyAnnotation, because the one you want select is only annotated with @MyAnnotation. I think @Any should not be necessary on Instance injection, because Instance will be capable of accessing all implementations of MyInterface, whereby you select the one annotated with @MyAnnotation(MyEnum.value). I have never used Instance with a qualifier, which uses a enum.

I think you shouldn't need to use Instace.
Is the following injection not working?

```
class MyDelegate implements MyInterface{

   @Inject
   @MyAnnotation(MyEnum.value)
   private MyInterface myInterface;
}
```

If you need to delegate to another implementation then maybe CDI-Decorators are what you need.

```
@Decorator
@Default // We decorate the default implementation of MyInterface or any qualified 
         // one you need to decorate
abstract class MyDecorator implements MyInterface {

   @Inject
   @MyAnnotation(MyEnum.value)
   private MyInterface myInterface;

   @Inject
   @Delegate
   private MyInterface delegate;

   // Implement all methods you want to decroate

   public void myMethod(){
      if(condition) {
         myInterface.myMethod();
      } else {
         delegate.myMethod();
      }
   }
}
```

You need to register the decorator in your beans.xml

```
<decorators>
    <class>MyDecorator</class>
</decorators>
```

Does that help you?

Comment: Hi Thomas ! Sorry for the late reply.
It doesn't help me because I want to get the enum value from a database.

Comment: Could you provide a lightweight maven based sample project on github which illustrates the issue? A would take look into it at the next days.